# Is it possible to set all characters in all vertex groups to lowercase?

Tags: objects, armature, bones, weight-painting, vertex-groups

So I've been working on porting several meshes from an older project into a new one, I however added capitalisation on a lot of vertex groups that I didn't have to. So now its _R instead of _r for example. Is there a way I could remove the capitalisation so its all lower case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It just so happens that I have a snippet of python that does exactly that:

```
import bpy
from bpy import context as C
import re

for vg in C.active_object.vertex_groups:
    new_name = vg.name.lower()
    print(vg.name, '->', new_name)
    if new_name != vg.name:
        vg.name = new_name
```